# how to create a protocol on top of tcp

Tags: tcp, ip, protocols

I want create a new protocol on the TCP/IP protocol.
I want that this protocol allow or not allow sending a file on the network's computers.
For example if a computer try to send a file 'a.exe' to another computer, my protocol can alarm to user on 2nd computer and if user perform then copy is true.
how i can create protocol?
best regards

Answer (score 0):

A new protocol won't help, they could just use another protocol, e.g. FTP, or rename the file to something innocuous. What you want to do is implement a firewall.

Comment: I want create a new protocol to avoid that a malware send on the network. for example a hacker may use sql injection and send a RAT malware to another computer and then manage victim computer remotely. i want create a protocol and avoid this attacks.

Comment: @user3164943 - again, a new protocol won't help you here. In this case, an antivirus utility would be recommended.

Comment: thanks for your response. indeed i want create a security architecture to manage attacks. this architecture must prevent any attacks in network layer. for example if a user try use SQLIA, my protocol can like SNMP protocol must save log and then avoid attacks...